Better way of coding this to get the data
These are the codes I am using right now.  It works for the most part on my home computer with only 3 files to create the codes.  Once I put it on my work computer which the code then goes through about 130 folders and pulls data from them.  It seems to take a while to do and not sure if there is a better way to code it.  The second problem is it only getting data up to 54 files and then seemed to stop getting the data, almost like it is looping back over the same folders. Third problem is it seems to open all the .xlsm files and not close them after getting the data and moving to the next file.  I would like to have this run in a Workbook open event so it will update the files when the workbook opens or at button to run the update.
Sub VBA_Loop_Through_all_Files_in_subfolders_Using_FSO_Early_Binding()
    'use const for fixed values
    Const FLDR As String = "C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Attendance"
    Const LIST_START_ADDR As String = "B12"
    
    Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject, oFolder As Object, c As range
    Dim oSFolderFile As Object, sFile As Object, sfolder As Object
    
    Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(FLDR)
    
    Set c = Sheet1.range(LIST_START_ADDR) 'start here
    
    For Each sfolder In oFolder.SubFolders     'loop through subfolders
        For Each sFile In sfolder.Files        'loop all files in each subfolder
            If sFile.Name Like "*.xlsm" Then   'do we want to list this file?
                c.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:=sFile.Path, _
                               TextToDisplay:=oFSO.GetBaseName(sFile.Name)
                Set c = c.Offset(1)            'next cell down
            End If 'is .xlsm file
            Next sFile
            Next sfolder
            
            
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim tmpArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim range As range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA PULL - TG")
        With ws
        
        lastRow = .range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lastRow
          If InStr(1, .range("B" & i).Value, " ") Then
               tmpArray = Split(.range("B" & i).Value, " ")
               .range("B" & i).Value = tmpArray(0)
               .range("C" & i).Value = tmpArray(1)
            End If
       Next i
        End With
        
        Call OpenHyperlinkAndCopyData
    
End Sub

Sub OpenHyperlinkAndCopyData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim cell As range
    Dim hyperlinkAddress As String
    Dim dataToCopy As Variant
    Dim hla As Object
   ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
      Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA PULL - TG")
    
    For Each cell In ws.range("B12:B208")
        If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            hyperlinkAddress = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
            Workbooks.Open hyperlinkAddress
            dataToCopy = Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD").range("C4").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD").range("E2").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD").range("E4").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD").range("F2").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD").range("F4").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 15).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD").range("H4").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 16).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD").range("C4").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 17).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("Perfect Attendance Incentive").range("C14").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("Perfect Attendance Incentive").range("D14").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("Perfect Attendance Incentive").range("C13").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("Perfect Attendance Incentive").range("D13").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("Perfect Attendance Incentive").range("C12").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 10).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("Perfect Attendance Incentive").range("D12").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 11).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("Perfect Attendance Incentive").range("C11").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 12).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("Perfect Attendance Incentive").range("D11").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 13).Value = dataToCopy
            dataToCopy = Sheets("Crewmember History with Balance").range("A1").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 14).Value = dataToCopy
            
            
            
            
            
          
        
       End If
    Next cell
End Sub


Is there only one level of nested folders?

Can you list the column headers?  If you do, I'll post a much better way to organize your code.

Not the actual path but similar "C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Attendance\Dealers"

I updated my answer to have it enumerate the column headers.  Funny thing is that I'm a Dealer and have wrote an Attendance Database for work.  Let me know if you have any questions.

GetAttendanceRecords.Count will return the total number of files.  GetAttendanceRecords only searches one level of subfolders.  Considering there are only 54 files being processed ot of 130, a recursive file search may be in order.
Option Explicit

Private Enum AttendanceColumns
    acLastName = 1
    acFirstName
    acSubFileTitle
    acCMNumber
    acCMStatus
    acCMHireDate
    acFourthQtrDateCheck
    acFourthQtrAwardEarned
    acFirstQtrDateCheck
    acFirstQtrAwardEarned
    acSecondQtrDateCheck
    acSecondQtrAwardEarned
    acThirdQtrDateCheck
    acThirdQtrAwardEarned
    acCurrentOccurrenceBalance
    acPhoneNumber
    acLastDateCalendarSaved
    acCMRecordedPosition
    acLastColumn = acCMRecordedPosition
End Enum
        
Sub UpdateAttendance()
    Const LIST_START_ADDR As String = "B12"
            
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = GetAttendanceRecords
    Dim Target As Range
            
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA PULL - TG")
        Set Target = .Range(LIST_START_ADDR)
        Range(Target, Target.End(xlDown)).Resize(, UBound(Data, 2)).ClearContents
        Target.Resize(UBound(Data), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
    End With
            
End Sub
        
Function GetAttendenceFiles() As Collection
    'Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Attendance"
    Const FolderPath As String = "D:\vba\sample data\temp"
    Dim Map As New Collection, FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject, File As File, Folder As Folder
                
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    For Each Folder In Folder.SubFolders
        For Each File In Folder.Files
            If File.Name Like "*.xlsm" Then Map.Add File
        Next
    Next
            
    Set GetAttendenceFiles = Map
            
End Function
        
Private Function GetAttendanceRecords()
    Dim Map As Collection
    Set Map = GetAttendenceFiles
            
    Dim Result As Variant, RowData As Variant
    Dim File As File
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To Map.Count
        Set File = Map(r)
                
        RowData = GetAttendanceRecord(File.Path)
                
        If r = 1 Then ReDim Result(1 To Map.Count, 1 To UBound(RowData))
        For c = 1 To UBound(RowData)
            Result(r, c) = RowData(c)
        Next
    Next
            
    GetAttendanceRecords = Result
End Function
        
Private Function GetAttendanceRecord(FilePath As String) As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
            
    Dim wsAttendanceRecord As Worksheet
    Dim wsPerfectAttendanceIncentive As Worksheet
    Dim wsCrewmemberHistoryWithBalance As Worksheet
            
    Set wsAttendanceRecord = wb.Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD")
    Set wsPerfectAttendanceIncentive = wb.Sheets("Perfect Attendance Incentive")
    Set wsCrewmemberHistoryWithBalance = wb.Sheets("Crewmember History with Balance")
            
    Dim Result(1 To acCMRecordedPosition) As Variant
    Dim Parts() As String, BaseName As String
    BaseName = Left(wb.Name, InStrRev(wb.Name, ".") - 1)
    Parts = Split(BaseName, ",")
            
    'Result(acLastName) = "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & FilePath & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & Parts(0) & Chr(34) & ")"
    Result(acLastName) = Parts(0)
    If UBound(Parts) = 1 Then Result(acFirstName) = Parts(1)

    ' Assign values to Result array
    Result(acSubFileTitle) = wsAttendanceRecord.Range("C4").Value
    Result(acCMNumber) = wsAttendanceRecord.Range("E2").Value
    Result(acCMStatus) = wsAttendanceRecord.Range("E4").Value
    Result(acFourthQtrDateCheck) = wsAttendanceRecord.Range("F2").Value
    Result(acFourthQtrAwardEarned) = wsPerfectAttendanceIncentive.Range("C14").Value
    Result(acFirstQtrDateCheck) = wsPerfectAttendanceIncentive.Range("D14").Value
    Result(acFirstQtrAwardEarned) = wsPerfectAttendanceIncentive.Range("C13").Value
    Result(acSecondQtrDateCheck) = wsPerfectAttendanceIncentive.Range("D13").Value
    Result(acSecondQtrAwardEarned) = wsPerfectAttendanceIncentive.Range("C12").Value
    Result(acThirdQtrDateCheck) = wsPerfectAttendanceIncentive.Range("D12").Value
    Result(acThirdQtrAwardEarned) = wsPerfectAttendanceIncentive.Range("C11").Value
    Result(acCurrentOccurrenceBalance) = wsPerfectAttendanceIncentive.Range("D11").Value
    Result(acPhoneNumber) = wsCrewmemberHistoryWithBalance.Range("A1").Value
    Result(acLastDateCalendarSaved) = wsAttendanceRecord.Range("F4").Value
    Result(acCMRecordedPosition) = wsAttendanceRecord.Range("H4").Value
            
    ' Return the result array
    GetAttendanceRecord = Result
            
    ' Close the workbook after use
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Function


It runs the code, however I'm not getting the first name into column C and the last name is coming up Vittur^J .....=HYPERLINK("C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Attendance\Vittur, Rose\Vittur, Rose.xlsm","Vittur^J").

Hey @RoseVittur, I fixed the issues.  You should get the correct number of files as long as there are no relevant files in a subfolder of "Dealers".

thank you very much.  I have on last question.  If I needed it to look in another file and do the same ie.  "C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Attendance\dual rate and up" (not Dealers) how would i do it.

@RoseVittur Modify GetAttendanceRecords() to add the files to the Map collection.

ok ty. New issue. Some folder names are Vsde, dkke (kide), and not pulling the first name. Where would i fix this or could you tell me.

Folder or file name? GetAttendanceRecord(FilePath) returns a single record.

SubFolder name column after it splits the name into columns. Column B (path..and shows last name), column C (First name).  Some folders names are listed like xxx, xxx (aka name).  The file is the same way ABC, XYZ (AKA NAME).XLSM.  It does pull the path correctly

@RoseVittur I modified it to split by the comma.  You'll have to put the comma back, if you want to keep it.

i got it to pull at least the first name correctly by adding this Result(acFirstName) = "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & FilePath & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & Parts(1) & Chr(34) & ")".  However don't need the hyperlink on it.  How can i do it without the hyperlink.

@RoseVittur I update the answer.

works great last thing that was thrown at me last night.  I need a small code that will run only 1 then i will take it out.  when each .xlsm file opens i need to change the formula in CrewmemberHistoryWithBalance.("A1") to =LOOKUP(2,1/('ATTENDANCE RECORD'!E:E<>""),'ATTENDANCE RECORD'!E:E).  Once it goes threw each folder the first time then the code will be removed.  Just looking for a quicker way than by hand lmao

You don't have a Workbook.Close in the code, try this.
Option Explicit

Sub OpenHyperlinkAndCopyData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, cel As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA PULL - TG")
    
    For Each cel In ws.Range("B12:B208")
        If cel.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(cel.Hyperlinks(1).Address, UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=True)
            With wb.Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD")
                cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = .Range("C4").Value
                cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = .Range("E2").Value
                cel.Offset(0, 4).Value = .Range("E4").Value
                cel.Offset(0, 5).Value = .Range("F2").Value
                cel.Offset(0, 15).Value = .Range("F4").Value
                cel.Offset(0, 16).Value = .Range("H4").Value
                cel.Offset(0, 17).Value = .Range("C4").Value
            End With
            
            With wb.Sheets("Perfect Attendance Incentive")
                 cel.Offset(0, 6).Value = .Range("C14").Value
                 cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = .Range("D14").Value
                 cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = .Range("C13").Value
                 cel.Offset(0, 9).Value = .Range("D13").Value
                 cel.Offset(0, 10).Value = .Range("C12").Value
                 cel.Offset(0, 11).Value = .Range("D12").Value
                 cel.Offset(0, 12).Value = .Range("C11").Value
                 cel.Offset(0, 13).Value = .Range("D11").Value
            End With
            cel.Offset(0, 14).Value = wb.Sheets("Crewmember History with Balance").Range("A1").Value
            
            wb.Close
       End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

